# FStar function strange behavior

Tags: fstar

It seems incorrect that the following simple function is accepted as a terminating one:

```
val fnc : (nw: nat) -> (ni: nat) -> (ni_max: nat) -> bool
let rec fnc nw ni ni_max =
  match ni with 
  | ni_max -> false
  | _      -> fnc nw (nw + ni) ni_max
```

Surprisingly, the function does terminate upon evaluating it, for instance, by `fnc 0 0 1` and returns `false`. What am I missing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ni_max` in the first branch of the pattern is a fresh binder and has no relation to the parameter `ni_max` of the function. Your code is equivalent to:

```
let rec fnc nw ni ni_max =
  match ni with 
  | _ -> false
  | _      -> fnc nw (nw + ni) ni_max
```

which is a function that always returns false.

You probably intended to write

```
let rec fnc nw ni ni_max =
  if ni = ni_max then false
  else fnc nw (nw + ni) ni_max
```

and now the termination checker should complain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nik. I indeed considered the case variable bound to the ni_max argument.