# Why isn't this FStar function accepted?

Tags: fstar

I'd like to understand why this function is not accepted as a terminating one:

```
val while_items: ni: nat -> ni_max: nat -> nw: nat -> bool
let rec while_items ni ni_max nw = 
  (if   ni < ni_max 
   then while_items (ni + nw) ni_max nw 
   else true)
```

FStar rejects it and sends the following message:

*(Error) Could not prove termination of this recursive call: The solver found a (partial) counterexample...*

It's likely not the same binding issue here as the one in my related question under [FStar function strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473795/fstar-function-strange-behavior)

Can FStar show the counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [the tutorial](http://www.fstar-lang.org/tutorial/), by default F* uses a decreases measure that puts all arguments in lexicographic order

```
val while_items: ni: nat -> ni_max: nat -> nw: nat -> Tot bool (decreases %[ni,ni_max;nw])
```

which doesn't work for proving this function terminating, since clearly `ni + nw` is not smaller than `ni`.

With a correct decreases measure and a precondition that `nw` is positive this does go through:

```
val while_items: ni: nat -> ni_max: nat -> nw: pos ->
  Tot bool (decreases (if ni < ni_max then ni_max-ni else 0))
```

Not exactly the original example, but that one definitely loops forever for `nw=0`! And anyway, even after this fix this code makes little sense as is and using such loops is not idiomatic for functional programming.

Finally, F* can't produce counterexamples, and this error message has recently been fixed: https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/pull/2075

Comment: Catalin, thank you for your answer. I'm moving something over from another system where several increasing while loops were employed and many of them used calculated increments; it appeared the easier way to emulate `while` in FStar. The code in my question is meant to be the while-template.

Answer (score 2):

This function does not terminate on all inputs. Consider `ni < ni_max` and `nw=0`. Unfortunately, F* does not find concrete counterexamples like this.

You can prove a variant of your function terminating, but you have to tell F* explicitly what's decreasing. Here we're using the well-founded ordering on nat.

```
let as_nat (x:int) : nat = if x < 0 then 0 else x
val while_items: ni: nat -> ni_max: nat -> nw: nat{ni < ni_max ==> nw > 0} -> Tot bool
                 (decreases (as_nat (ni_max - ni)))
let rec while_items ni ni_max nw =
  (if   ni < ni_max
   then while_items (ni + nw) ni_max nw
   else true)
```